# bluez endpoints not working for an audio source

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian, bluez, speaker

I am trying to play audio from Raspbian to a bluetooth speaker using A2DP.

From looking at `test/simple-endpoint` in the bluez source, it appears that running it without arguments should register an endpoint with the `A2DP_SOURCE_UUID` of `0000110A-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`. However, I don't see any of the endpoint's callback methods being called (`SelectConfiguration`/`SetConfiguration`) when using `bluetoothctl` to connect to a bluetooth speaker. I tried with two different types of bluetooth speakers.

If I instead run `simple-endpoint` in "sbcsink" mode, and then connect my phone to it, I do see the endpoint's methods called (`SelectConfiguration`/`SetConfiguration`). So endpoints appear to be working for the A2DP sink uuid, but not the source one.

I'm able to find a `org.bluez.MediaTransport1` corresponding to the bluetooth speaker by iterating through dbus managed objects:

```python
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/'), 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
for path, ifaces in manager.GetManagedObjects().items():
    transport = ifaces.get('org.bluez.MediaTransport1')
    if transport is None:
        continue
    transport_obj = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.bluez', path), 'org.bluez.MediaTransport1')
    (fd, read_mtu, write_mtu) = transport_obj.Acquire('w')
    taken_fd = fd.take()
    print(path, fd, taken_fd, read_mtu, write_mtu)
```

I'm able to write to the transport's file descriptor `taken_fd`, but I can't control the audio configuration like I think I would if the transport had been acquired via a `org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1`. Also this seems kinda hacky, I'm not sure this transport is meant for me to access in this way. I would expect to get access to the transport via `MediaEndpoint1`'s `SetConfiguration`.

I observed this behavior with bluez 5.43 on Rasbian Stretch. I also tried updating to the latest bluez 5.50 and saw the same behavior.

What is the expected way to use bluez as an audio source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem by running `bluetoothd` in debug mode, and found that `SetConfiguration`/`SetConfiguration` was being called on a previously registered endpoint with a path of `/A2DP/SBC/Source/1`. Searching online for this path led me to discover that it was associated with `bluealsa`, which was registering the endpoint on system startup, and then was receiving the media endpoint callbacks instead of my endpoint. After killing `bluealsa`, my audio source endpoint was then able to receive the media endpoint callbacks as expected.